# Unknown php unset error

Tags: php, arrays, unset

I have problem in deleting an element of array. Look:

```
<?php
session_start();
$i = 0;
$expected = $_GET['name'];
foreach($_SESSION['chart'] as $name)
{
     if($name==$expected)
     {
         break;
     }
     $i++;
}
unset($_SESSION['chart'][$i]);

echo count($_SESSION['chart'])." ".$expected." ".$i;
//echo "<script>history.go(-1);</script>";
?>
```

I'm getting this output: 3 name 2.

I know that element in array exists with name 'name', but I can't unset it. Please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not let PHP do the search?

```
<?php
session_start();
$key = array_search($_GET['name'], $_SESSION['chart']);
if ($key !== false) {
   unset($_SESSION['chart'][$key]);
}
```

Comment: If that one works for you, you should mark his answer as correct.  The only thing I could see is maybe your keys were not sequential for some reason, in which case unset might not point to the right key.  :)

Comment: Well...with PHP you're dealing with a huge box full of tools. You just need to get used to searching first if PHP can do something for you. No need to implement a search yourself. ;)

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I couldn't mark answer cause it displayed me box with "wait 3 minutes"...

Answer (score 1):

because you call unset out of foreach

try :

```
foreach($_SESSION['chart'] as $name)
{
if($name==$expected)
{
    unset($name);
}
$i++;
}
```

Comment: No. It's not in it. I have tried to make it in array and it not works too.

Comment: This is my code for adding to array:
$_SESSION['chart'][] = $name;

Comment: when you unset($name) is like  you did unset($_SESSION['chart'][$i])

Comment: Well...this is just wrong. Using `unset($name)` here will do nothing but delete the local variable. It will do nothing at all to the global array.

Answer (score 1):

You can make your intent clearer by using this form of foreach

```
foreach($_SESSION['chart'] as $idx=>$name)
{
     if($name==$expected)
     {
         unset($_SESSION['chart'][$idx]);
         break;
     }
}
```

However, [Till Helge Helwig's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9443308/6521) is better for this particular problem, but it's worth being aware that you don't need to maintain your own 'key' variable when using foreach.

Comment: Of all the solutions using `foreach` this is the only reasonable one. There is no need to do the iteration over the array manually though. :)

Comment: Yours is the better solution for the problem at hand though. But I thought it would be useful to show you don't have to maintain your own key variable.